# Is it possible to install MySQL on CentOS 6.6?

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm asking this question because I've never faced so many problems on other OS (Windows, Ubuntu) and I've never seen so many threads and comments from people saying that they cannot install `mysql-community-server` on CentOS, because of missing dependencies. I wish there was a command (I think there is one in Ubuntu) that would make complete installation with all dependencies.

So, this is what I've done and what I have now:

```
# wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
# yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
# yum install mysql-community-server
```

After I run the last command I get a whole list of dreadful messages (they are not in English and I cannot easily copy-paste them here), but among them I see such messages, like `Required: libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.16) (64)` and `Required: libmysqlclient.so.16() (64 bit)`. To repair it, I tried to run this command:

```
$ yum install mysql-devel
```

But again get another list of error messages. Finally, I should add that CentOS version is 6.6. I hope, someone can provide a step-by-step tutorial of `MySQL` installation on `CentOS`. Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is what I done:

1. removed old mysql repos with `yum remove ...`
2. Downloaded a new repo with `# yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm`
3. As you can see, a new repo should be for CentOS 6 (exactly what I have).
   After that I ran `# yum install mysql-community-server`

But in the console I see that for some insane reason CentOS still tries to install `mysql57...el7-7...`. What the heck is going on? I do not have `mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm` any more on my machine, I have `el6`. WHy does it refer to the incorrect version???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed incorrect version.

This link "http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm" is for centos 7.7

Uninstall that and look out for correct version. If you have internet connectivity use these commands

```
sudo yum -y install mysql-server
sudo yum -y install mysql-connector-java
```

Comment: And can you please advise how to uninstall on CentOS?

Comment: Oh, man. I removed an old repo, downloaded a new verion of `mysql57` for `centos 6` (`# wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm`), followed the same steps and got exactly the same error messages. So, unfortunatelly, it does not help.

Comment: Please, have a look at my question. I posted some new information. Probably, you know how to help.

Comment: Run "yum remove mysql*" Delete all repo files Run yum install commands posted in the response

Comment: Should I run these commands after `# yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm` ?

Comment: Or should they do all the job themselves?

Comment: well, when I simply do "yum remove mysql*", I get a message - "no packages to remove". I

Comment: I should be `yum remove "mysql*"`. Then it works. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96699/discussion-between-durga-viswanath-gadiraju-and-jacobian).